# Python: most elegant way of accessing __version__ inside main()

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, version, argparse

I am creating a small Python 3 program that takes command line arguments using `argparse`. This library has an automatic way of handling version flags. I am trying to figure out what is the most elegant way of accessing **version** inside my `main()` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse


def main():

    __version__ = '0.1.0'

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input',
                        type=str,
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version',
                        action='version',
                        version='%(prog)s ' + __version__
                        )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # main code
    print('foo bar')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So what is the most elegant solution here?

1) do what I did above and just live with it.

2) leave `__version__` outside `main()` and pass it as an argument to `main()` (though I always thought it was bad practise to use arguments in a `main()` function)

3) leave `__version__ and all parser setup outside`main()`and pass the variable`args` to main() as an argument (bad practise again).

4) <strike>use global variables</strike>

Or am I mistaken that it is bad practise to send arguments to `main()`? Or alternatively, am I missing another solution altogether?

Comment: The `argparse.py` file has a `__version__` assignment right at the start of the file.  It's a hold over from when the module was an independent pypi.  Making it a module constant is logical since it's a property of the module, and should be obvious to readers, and accessible when imported.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the message. I think most packages define `__version__` at the start in that manner and I also think that's the most elegant way of doing it. But the difference is that packages, in general, do not need to access this value in any of its functions; it's just there to be accessed by the user using `package.__version__`. In my case above, I will need to access it from within a `main()` function or similar. So unless I am misunderstanding something, I still have the same issue: how to elegantly access this `__version__` value inside of a function without using globals?

Comment: You can freely use that variable inside your `main`.  You only need to define it as a `global` if you intend to modify it within the `main`.  Simple ('read') use of an externally defined variable is quite ok.

Comment: On a differ issue, if the parser definition is long, it may be a good idea to define it in its own function.  Either call it from within `main`, or pass its `args` to `main`.  Visually that separates the input parsing code from the use code which should be the content of the `main`.

Comment: Yes, definitely defining the parser separately is a better approach, I just tried to create a minimal example as concise as I could. As for the use `global`, I agree that it might make sense to use it in this case, particularly since the state of that variable is not changed. If you would like to create an answer with this, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @hpaulj forgot to mention your username so that you'd receive a notification of my reply.

Comment: It notified me, I think because your comment immediately followed mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
__version__ = '0.1.0'

def main():
    # optionally put this argparse code in its own function
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input',
                        type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version',
                        action='version',
                        version='%(prog)s ' + __version__
                        )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # main code
    print(args)
    print('foo bar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

testing

```
1136:~/mypy$ python3 stack57822847.py foobar
Namespace(input='foobar')
foo bar
1136:~/mypy$ python3 stack57822847.py -v
stack57822847.py 0.1.0
```

Comment: I had never comes across the concept of implicitly global variables before. This clarifies the issue and is certainly the most elegant solution, much appreciated.